Cubing the cube - as 'perfectly' as possible
Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square
A perfect cubing of a cube is a partition of the cube into some finite number of smaller cubes that are pair-wise non-congruent. The above page gives a nice proof that perfect cubing is impossible.

How to cut a cube into the least number of cubes so that only 2 of the smaller cubes are mutually congruent?

Note: Whether this construction is possible or not, we can replace 2 with 3, 4... to generate other questions (obviously, if 8 of the smaller cubes can be congruent, the problem becomes trivial). Alternatively, one can consider 2 pairs of mutually congruent cubes etc.
These questions could have analogs in higher dimensions.

It is not even clear whether there is an integer cube that can be decomposed into smaller cubes, none of which appear more than SEVEN times.  i couldn't construct one.

Thank you. Thus there appear to be at least 6 (in fact many more) questions - 2 of the cubes identical, 3 identical, 2 different pairs of mutually identical cubes and so forth. Just a hunch: with 4 of the smaller cubes identical, one might have a better chance than with 7 identical. I don't know how to even begin though.
